# align td of table to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my app I have a table which has `tr` like below

```
<tr>
  <td><strong>Item Total:</strong></td>
  <td><strong style = "float:right">₹975.00</strong></td>
</tr>
```

I want to move first `td` close to my second td. When I apply css like `margin-left:20px;`, It does the trick for me, but It also moves my other `tr`'s `td` too. Which I don't want to happen.

My other `tr` is like below

```
<tr>
   <td class="item-image"><img alt="Loose" 
   src="loose.png1466140997"> </td>
   <td class="item-name">Loose Tea</td>
   <td class="item-qty">1</td>
   <td class="item-price">₹200.00</td>
</tr>
```

Below is the similar [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzyv7r8t/2/).

Please help.

Comment: try this <td align="right"><strong>Item Total:</strong></td>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="item-image"><img alt="Loose" 
   src="loose.png1466140997"> </td>
   <td class="item-name">Loose Tea</td>
   <td class="item-qty">1</td>
   <td class="item-price">₹200.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>Item Total:</strong></td>
    <td><strong style = "float:right" >₹975.00</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Rockers Technology has the right answer for you. Except for the "align" part, which is depraceted with HTML5. Use CSS instead.

**HTML**

```
<tr><td colspan="3" class="text-right"><strong>Item Total:</strong></td><td><strong style="float: right;">₹975.00</td></tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-right { text-align: right; }
```

And can some one told me, why i cant use linebreaks in code snippets? -.-